Multiple identify validation parameters for lexik-jwt bundle?
What I'm trying to achieve is specifiying inside the .yaml path multple identity-parameters to validate users with the lexik-jwt bundle. Currently, only emails are working as an identifier. However, I want both to work, a custom nickname/username AND an email, meaning that it's redundant which of these two is given, the functionality shall remain. My parameter for this is being specified in the path
security/firewalls/main/json_login/username_path: email inside the "security.yaml" config-file.
This is the entire files content:
security:
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
password_hashers:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    App\Entity\User: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
    users:
        entity:
            class: App\Entity\User
            property: email

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/_(profiler|wdt)
        security: false
    api:
        pattern: ^/api/
        stateless: true
        provider: users
        jwt: ~
    main:
        stateless: true
        provider: users
        json_login:
            check_path: auth # The name in routes.yaml is enough for mapping
            username_path: email
            password_path: password
            success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
            failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
        jwt: ~

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/auth, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }

